# ProjectedFields working in SPQuery but not in the View

Tags: caml-query, spquery, spview

I've three lists: Competitions, Works and WorksVotes, linked to each other through Lookup fields.
WorksVotes list has Lookup field to Works list, and Works list has Lookup field to Competitions list.
What I need is to display the Competition in the WorksVotes list.
I wrote some CAML code with 2 Joins which works fine with SPQuery object:

```
var query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" /></OrderBy>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" /><FieldRef Name=\"Attachments\" /><FieldRedf Name=\"LinkTitle\" /><FieldRef Name=\"CompetitionTitle\" />";
query.Joins =@"<Join Type=""INNER"" ListAlias=""worksList"">
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name=""CompetitionWork"" RefType=""ID"" />
<FieldRef Name=""ID"" List=""worksList"" />
</Eq>
</Join>
<Join Type=""INNER"" ListAlias=""competitionsList"">
<Eq>
<FieldRef List=""worksList"" Name=""Competition"" RefType=""ID"" />
<FieldRef List=""competitionsList"" Name=""ID"" />
</Eq>
</Join>";
query.ProjectedFields = "<Field Name=\"CompetitionTitle\" Type=\"Lookup\" List=\"competitionsList\" ShowField=\"Title\" />";
```

After testing I added this CAML into schema.xml file that defines the WorksVotes list:

```
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name="Title"></FieldRef>
...
<FieldRef Name="CompetitionTitle"></FieldRef>
</ViewFields>
<Joins>
<Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="worksList">
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name="CompetitionWork" RefType="ID" />
<FieldRef Name="ID" List="worksList" />
</Eq>
</Join>
<Join Type="INNER" ListAlias="competitionsList">
<Eq>
<FieldRef List="worksList" Name="Competition" RefType="ID" />
<FieldRef List="competitionsList" Name="ID" />
</Eq>
</Join>
</Joins>
<ProjectedFields>
<Field Name="CompetitionTitle" Type="Lookup" List="competitionsList" ShowField="Title" />
</ProjectedFields>
```

But in this case I get an SPException telling that the "CompetitionTitle" field is unavailable or does not exist.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This really intrigued me so I invested an hour into analysis of the problem.

First of all, I was able to show the view using unchanged OP's declarative description of the view:
[image]

Unfortunately, to achieve this I had to change internal state of variables inside `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll`. Conclusion, you can't do this without recompiling SharePoint or injecting code.

A little more information for anyone interested. There is a bug in `SPFieldCollection` class, method `InitializeProjectedFields()`. Instead of current implementation of `for` loop:

```
for (int k = this.m_iCount; k < (this.m_iCount + this.ProjectedFields.get_Count()); k = (int) (k + 1))
{
    string str5 = "<Field/>";
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(str5);
    XmlNode documentElement = document.DocumentElement;
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "Type", "Lookup");
    SPGlobal.SetNamedBoolItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "ReadOnly", true);
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "DisplayName", this.projectedFields.get_Item((int) (k - this.m_iCount)).strName);
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "ID", Guid.Empty.ToString());
    this.FieldsSafeArrayFullXML[k] = documentElement;
}
```

this should be implemented:

```
for (int k = this.m_iCount; k < (this.m_iCount + this.ProjectedFields.get_Count()); k = (int) (k + 1))
{
    string str5 = "<Field/>";
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(str5);
    XmlNode documentElement = document.DocumentElement;
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "Type", "Lookup");
    SPGlobal.SetNamedBoolItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "ReadOnly", true);
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "DisplayName", this.projectedFields.get_Item((int) (k - this.m_iCount)).strName);
    SPGlobal.SetNamedStringItem(documentElement.OwnerDocument, documentElement, "ID", Guid.Empty.ToString());
    this.FieldsSafeArrayFullXML[k] = documentElement.OuterXml;
}
```

Notice the `OuterXml` missing on the last line of current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to make projected fields work in views (either defined programmatically or declaratively), I sadly conclude that one cannot use fields from other lists in views by help of Joins and Projected Fields.